# getting error while importing created package in another directory

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/my-jsx-package/src/Index.jsx 5:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:2)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  | const Button = ({ onClick, children }) => {
  |   return (

> {children}

|   )
| };

webpack compiled with 1 error

am trying to import my package in another directory locally , then getting these error
ERROR in ./node_modules/my-jsx-package/src/Index.jsx 5:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (5:2)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  | const Button = ({ onClick, children }) => {
  |   return (

> {children}

|   )
| };

webpack compiled with 1 error

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.